# How to prolong hover lasting time in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, hover

```
a:hover + #menu {
display: block;
position: fixed;
```

}

This is the css for my hover which is supposed to display a menu.But it instantly disappears when I take off the mouse, what can I do here? Would doing this through JS be better and how would I go with that?

This is the div for this menu.It is part of a td which is part of the main table which is the main part of the site

```
<div id="menu">
   <button><a href="#igradesno1">COD WW2</button>
   <button><a href="#igra2levo">Destiny 2</button>
   <button><a href="#wolfensteindesno">Wolfenstein</button>
   <button><a href="#forhonor1">For Honor</button>
   <button><a href="#fifa182">Fifa 18</button>



 </div>
```

Comment: Is the behavior you want that when a user takes their mouse away from the menu item, the hover stays for a period of time?

Comment: Yeah, thats the desired behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `display: block` and `none`, try use opacity, and CSS transitions.

I've created a simple JSfiddle to demonstrate

https://jsfiddle.net/3q0v5ufh/